# 11 cylinders intercepted

Tags: geometry

I have been working on this problem for about(over) two months now. This is **not school work**.
The final objective of this problem is to find the **area** of these **11 cylinders** which are enclosed in a sphere.

In the image below, every line represents the center of a cyllinder.

$a = 60^{\circ}$ and $b = 30^{\circ}$
$r_{cylinder} = 0.5mm$
$length_{each\,cylinder} = 1.5mm$

Notice that although the cylinders are `1.5mm` in length, they are completely connected, like if grabbed the image below and enlarged, meaning that the base will always be inside of the total object.

[image: from above]

This second picture shows the that there is also two other cylinders perpendicular to the other 9.

This problem came to me when I read about the Steinmetz Solid, and wondered what would happen if I aligned them in this specific formation, simple curiosity.

[image: from side]

Then, all of this is enclosed in a sphere of a radius of `1.5mm`

Comment: Sorry , may be I dont understand very well , you said every line represents the center of a cylinde  ??!! did you mean the axis of the cylinder  ??

Comment: I am also confused by the values of $a$ and $b$ . May be the picture is not clear , or I am seeing that   2$a$ 's are covered by  3$ b$'s, and so $90°= 120°$ !!!

Comment: @Nizar yes, that is exactly what I meant, and the values a and b are angles. I'm stating that there is 6 cillinders that are evenly spaced, and I also have three more cillinders that are evenly spaced in between four of the cillinders

Comment: What do you mean by “the area of these 11 cylinders”?  The surface area of the union solid?  The surface area of the intersection solid?  If the cylinders end at the same centre, and some pairs are collinear, then the intersection is empty.

Comment: @AntonSherwood of the union solid

Comment: Well I don't know off the top of my head what the surface area of your union solid would be, but it must be less than $22\pi$, the combined surface area of eleven cylinders with your given dimensions

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant? (Sorry I can't put an image in a comment.)

[image: Your thing]

The sphere is partially transparent so you can see the cylinders inside.

Comment: exactly what I meant

Answer (score 0):

For this problem consider sun .The ball  is centre and rays are the cylinders so the area of the 11 cylinders would be a shape like a flat tyre like cylinder whose radius is length  of the small cylinders and height is the diameter of small cylinders .This my way of thinking. Soory if I have interpreted something wrong.!!